# Parsing XHTML with inline tags

Tags: iphone, xml, cocoa, nsxmlparser, libxml2

I'm trying to parse an XHTML document using TBXML on the iPhone (although I would be happy to use either libxml2 or NSXMLParser if it would be easier). I need to extract the content of the body as a series of paragraphs and maintain the inline tags, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
       <title>Title</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="body">
          <div>
             <h3>Title</h3>
             <p>Paragraph with <em>inline</em> tags</p>
             <img src="image.png" />
          </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to extract the paragraph but maintain the `<em>inline</em>` content with the paragraph, all my testing so far has extracted that as a subelement without me knowing exactly where it fitted in the paragraph.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Apologies for the formatting, I have tried to edit but for some reason I get an error.

Comment: user290796: Because you tried to use inline code font where you needed to use a code block. See http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption 1. You are only interested in the data in the p (paragraph) element and that you are using NSXMLParser.

Assumption 2. You want to keep any element inside of p intact.

The strategy that you want to use is to create a state machine for your parser so that it knows when it needs to save data and when to ignore data as it is received.

Set up your `NSXMLParser delegate` using the sample code from Apple.
Your delegate will need an ivar `BOOL inParagraph` for tracking when data will be retained or discarded. The initial value of `inParagaph` is `NO`. 
When your delegate receives the `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` message, `if ([element isEqual:@"p"])` clear your `receivedData` variable and set `inParagraph = YES`

EDIT: receivedData is an NSMutableString. Fixed the code examples

At this point your `parser delegate` wants to save data received.

When the `parser delegate` receives the `parser:foundCharacters:` message, append the string to `receivedData` as in the sample code.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (inParagraph) [receivedData appendString:string];
}
```

When the parser encounters the inline element, the delegate will receive the `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` again. This is when the `inParagraph` state variable is important. The parser will not receive the enclosing '<' and '>' characters of an element, so you will have to wrap the `elementName` in the '<' and '>' characters and add to `receivedData`. Something like

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{ if (inParagraph) 
    {
        NSString *inlineElementName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>", elementName];
        [receivedData appendString:inlineElementName];
    }
....
}
```

When the `parser delegate` receives the `parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:` message, it checks whether it is in the "p" element, `if (inParagraph  && ![elementName isEqual:@"p"]`, close the inline element. `if ([elementName isEqual:@"p"])` add the contents of `receivedData` to the `NSMutableArray` holding your paragraphs.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
   if (inParagraph)
        {
             if (![elementName isEqual:@"p"])
                 { 
                      NSString *inlineElementName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"</%@>", elementName];
                     [receivedData appendString:inlineElementName];             
                 } else { // received closing </p> tag add receivedData to the paragraph array
                          [paragraphsArray addObject:[receivedData copy]];
                          [self setInParagraph:NO];
                         }
                 }
       }
}
```